Apache Echarts hide y axis (vertical) entry if no value is in zoom
If we have this chart type (Profile)
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-profile&random=b
I was not able to find any documentation on how, if zoomed into a section where the y value (category C) has no bar (such as at the very end of the example), it can "hide" the category C value so the vertical space can get reassigned to both category A and B.
I tried to consult the documentation on conditional hiding of a y axis value but was only able to find solutions to hide the whole y axis.
I expect that when zoomed in, a y value which is not in frame by a bar chart is not shown at all and reapers when zooming out as soon as it would be shown again.

You can listen to the dataZoom event, check if data is outside of the zoomed range and remove the category from ``yAxis.data` if neccessary.

Adding the following code to the example should work:
Example:
const endTime = Math.max.apply(null, data.map(item => item.value[2]));
myChart.on('dataZoom', function(params) {
  let range = endTime - startTime;
  let startValue = startTime + (range * 0.01 * params.start);
  let endValue = startTime + (range * 0.01 * params.end);
  let rest = data.filter(item => item.value[1] < endValue && item.value[2] > startValue);
  let remainingCategories = new Set();
  for (let item of rest) {
    remainingCategories.add(categories[item.value[0]]);
  }
  myChart.setOption({series: [{data: []}]});
  myChart.setOption({yAxis: {data: Array.from(remainingCategories)}, series: [{data: data}]});
});


Thanks, the solution using the dataZoom event works nicely when scaling using the bar at the bottom. When using the mouse zoom (by scrolling) the dataZoom event has a batch object with multiple dataZoom objects. This is no problem though as altering the code should be pretty easy. Thank you for the insight!

So by adding
if('batch' in params)   {     params = params.batch[0];   }   
To the top of the function is a quick and dirty fix
